# Cannot start OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-server

I am not able to start OpenVPN. All I see is

```
service openvpn start
 * Starting virtual private network daemon(s)...                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 * Autostarting VPN 'server'
```

Nothing more, but when I do

```
service openvpn status
 * VPN 'server' is not running
```

I am clueless. I've looked everywhere. I saw suggestions of a bad config, so I remade it and nothing.

Comment: Start `openvpn` manually, as follows: `sudo openvpn --config /path/to/config/file` and, provided there is no **daemon** statement inside the config file (if there is, remove it), error messages will spew out, and give you a hint of what there is to do.

Comment: thanks that helped alot! i was getting 
Options error: --tls-auth fails with 'ta.key': No such file or directory
i just comment the related on the config and it worked

Comment: Using --tls-auth is highly recommended.  It is a strong openvpn security mechanism.  See Openvpn [Hardening](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#security)